# How to change curtime?

Tags: mysql, time

How to change curtime value in MySQL, I run query `SELECT CURTIME()` and the result is `18:49:12`.

I want to change the value to `17:49:12`

If anyone knows a good way to do this I'd very much appreciate your help.

Comment: CURTIME() should return the current server time. So maybe you can change the time of the MySQL host.

Comment: Can you only query the database directly, or are you running this from an application? You should never use any data-altering method directly in a SQL statement, but rather in the application itself.

Answer (score 2):

CURTIME() value is a value based on server timezone. You can change server timezone:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Or do this with MySQL function ADD_DATE():

```
SELECT SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could be set the `time-zone` manually, like so:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-1:00';
```

or to set to your system time:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = SYSTEM;
```

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I don't think you can do this. It would imply that mysql can change the system time !

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a different time zone, you could apply timezone **OR** if u always want to get 1 hour before current time you could reduce the current time by 1 hour