# mysql retrieve data from a range of time from table

Tags: mysql

-[*this is the table of picture i want to retrieve datas from*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rJSa.png##)

---

I need two queries.

- the first one is to get the actionNo of the latest stopTime before the current time.
- the second query is to get the actionNo if the latest actionTime before the current time.

**Example:**

If the current time was: 00:46:20

- the first query is to get actionNo 9 (stoptime: 00:45:00)
- the second query is to get actionNo 8 (actiontime: 00:41:30)

-[this is eg of range to get data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XHsj.png)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: i want to retrieve the action number \/_\/.

Comment: What is first actionTime? the latest actionTime before the current time? Do you need two queries or both criteria in one query?

Comment: first actionTime is from to get in the time in the row of actiontime start from current time  
and  next actionTime is from next row of this.

Comment: Which result do you want to have if the current time was: 00:46:20?

Comment: for e.g let id =120 is first then the first action be 00:01:30 and the second action time is from id=1 00:06:30; please  see to the picture i poste,

Comment: If the current time was: 00:46:20 the first query is to get actionNo 8,and the second query is to get actionNo 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM timestuff WHERE `actionTime` < CURTIME();
SELECT MAX(id) FROM timestuff WHERE `stopTime` < CURTIME();
```

This gets you the latest id of the action/stoptime before the current time, will work if your table always is in the order as you have shown (that means, ids display the chronology of your time values - which isn't the case in your data as I just noticed).

**For your case:** you can take another step and add a inner join on the time closest to the current time and then look up the id of that data.

First query: For the latest stopTime before the current time:

```
SELECT
    timestuff.id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(stopTime) AS maxTime
        FROM
            timestuff
        WHERE
            `stopTime` < CURTIME()
    ) AS time
INNER JOIN timestuff ON timestuff.`stopTime` = time.maxTime;
```

Second query: For the first actionTime after the current time:

```
SELECT
    timestuff.id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(actionTime) AS minTime
        FROM
            timestuff
        WHERE
            `actionTime` > CURTIME()
    ) AS time
INNER JOIN timestuff ON timestuff.`actionTime` = time.minTime;
```

Comment: but the two show 120 only

Comment: I want to get the result if current time is 16:54:00 then the fist query result is actionNo of 65 and  the secnod query result is actionNo of 66. \/_\/

Comment: Have you tried the inner join query? The first queries fail because you have the dataset with 120 on top, I didn't see it when writing them, but that's the kind of problem I mentioned when adding the query with the inner join

Comment: /\_/\ the first query is ok, please help me to get he second query,please

Comment: you just have to switch actionTime with stopTime for the second query

Comment: the second query seems not correct i want the result if the current time is  between first row of stop time 00:00:00 and second row of stop time 00:05:00, then the first query is to retrieve 120.

Comment: " then the first query is to retrieve 120" - the second you mean? please be careful to write consistent when reporting which query doesn't work or things will get confusing. What value does it return instead?

Comment: for the second query is if the current time is between the action time of 00:01:30 of (fist row) and the second row of actionTime 00:06:30 then, it should output actionNo one (1).

Comment: So you want to retrieve the first row after the current time?

Comment: for query 1 ,if the current time is between first row of stop time 00:05:00 and second row of stop time 00:10:00, then the first query is to retrieve actionNo1. And for query 2, if the current time is between the action time of 00:06:30 of (fist row) and the second row of actionTime 00:11:30 then, it should output actionNo 2. please help me. \/_\/

Comment: in the second query, is actionNo 2 the second row?

Comment: yes ,to retrieve the first row if the currentime is  between the first row of stop time and second row of stop time.

Comment: to retrive the second row if the current time is between the first row of actionTime and second row of actionTime.

Comment: I edited the query and put them into the correct order (I think!), so the query looking for the stopTime is the first query and the one looking for the actionTime is the second query

Comment: Thank You very much /\_/\. It's now work.And please help me how to set time zone for CURTIME() function.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12140664/3595565, can't add more to it

Comment: Thanks you very much. /\_/\